# Change the date format in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 Express database that has been installed on a server in Germany. I created a database and have now realised the date formats are incorrect. I need to show each date as dd/mm/yyyy.

When I run dbcc useroptions (after making some changes to the server), I get the following -

```
language       dateformat  
-------------------------
British        dmy
```

When I run `select GetDate()` in a new query, it shows the date as follows -

```
2014-08-28 13:53:10.550
```

The bottom line issue is when I enter `28/08/2014` in to a textbox on a web forms project, it errors

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
selP.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbStartDate.Text);
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I have created a new user since changing the settings to British and dmy, which still produces the same error.

Comment: This is a .net problem.  I have added the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to achieve that is to set the culture of your web application.

[How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Perfect, I added <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" /> to the web.config and it worked ok.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is **shown** to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are dependent on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

Answer (score 0):

IN SQL, you need to cast that string as a DATETIME before inserting or updating the database.

```
CAST('28/08/2014' AS DATETIME)
```

You can change the format a date is displayed in using the CONVERT. For example, the following will display the date in UK short format (dd/mm/yyyy)

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), GetDate(), 103)
```

If you are doing this in C#, you need to detect the local culture and cast the string to a datetime as approporate.

```
//You can set the culture on the current thread:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture; // or new CultureInfo("en-GB"); //dd/MM/yyyy

//or you can pass it to the DateTime.Parse method. Something like this:
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(tbStartDate.Text, CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);

DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbStartDate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat)
```

Comment: There is no stored procedure inserting this date so no cast can be done. I have updated the question with the C# line that does this. The application works fine when entering 28/08/2014 on a server in the UK.

Comment: The issue is not the displaying of the date, its the inserting of a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
selP.StartDate=tbStartDate.Text.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `GETDATE()` function returns the system date and time in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm' irrespective of the `Dateformat`.Date format for SQL server is in U.S. date format `MM/DD/YY`, unless a localized version of SQL Server is installed which seems to be the case here.
Use

```
SET DATEFORMAT <format>
```

which sets the order of the date parts (month/day/year) for entering datetime or smalldatetime data. Valid parameters include mdy, dmy, ymd, ydm, myd, and dym. The U.S. English default is mdy.

This method allows you use a date format for dates sent to SQL Server of d/m/y, but it is connection dependent. If a new connection is made to SQL Server or if the server is stopped and restarted, the date format will go back to dmy which is default in your case.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), GetDate(), 103)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), JoiningDate, 103)from Employee where EmpId='1001'
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation? As it stands it's not very clear how this relates to the question.